# Entity framework child is null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I'm new to EntityFramework, so the question could be a bit stupid, but I've tried to searching google and found nothing.

I've got a table in db:

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Mask { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public DateTime Generated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public bool isElite { get; set; }
```

where UserProfile Owner is a link to another table.
When I make a selection like so:

```
 db.Keys.Where(s=>s.Owner.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && s.DateTo > DateTime.UtcNow).ToList()
```

It works well, but when I am trying to reach Owner from the licence it's always null.
Can someone please help how to get the Owner with a license?
Thank you for your time!

EDIT:
I think I made a mistake and posted a question a bit incorrectly. What I truly need is when I am searching license by its ID like:
    `License license = db.Keys.Find(id);`
I could get the owner like:
    `var a = license.Owner;`
I've used Active Record before, and it loaded such data "on demand" (only when I make a call to it). Can I do this somehow with EF?

Comment: How are Keys and License objects related? Is the Entity Set Name "Keys" while the Entity name is "License"? I would think so based on your code sample. Clarifying this should help us better understand your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the code you have, you can lazy load the Owner by marking it as `virtual` in the license class.

Since you are still in the context (using db), EF will automatically call to hydrate the `Owner`.

For a good article on loading related entities [check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx).

EDIT (query with linq):

Here is an example of what the linq query might look like, but you still might need to either lazy or eager load Owners.

```
var query = from k in db.Keys
            where k.Owner.UserId.Equals(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
            && k.DateTo > DateTime.UtcNow
            select k;

var list = query.ToList();
```

Comment: And if I want to have owner only for specific values? LzyLoading will make additional request for each found row, but all I need is to find owner like so: License license = db.Keys.Find(id); var o = license.Owner; (for a particular License, not for each)

Comment: sorry, could you show a little example please? I just have no ideas on how to make it with linq...

Comment: this does exactly, what does the line b.Keys.Where(s=>s.Owner.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && s.DateTo > DateTime.UtcNow).ToList()    Ive edited my post, look at edit please, I think, I described the problem not very clear for the first time.

Comment: @CodeDemen To pull like Active Record change this: `public UserProfile Owner { get; set; }` to this `public virtual UserProfile Owner { get; set; }`

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the DbQuery.Include(string path) Method
[Click here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery%601.Include%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework)

That at least does the trick for me.

Here would be your code:

> db.Keys.Include("Owner").Where(s=>s.Owner.UserId ==
>   WebSecurity.CurrentUserId && s.DateTo > DateTime.UtcNow).ToList()

This might not be the best method if you expect your "Keys" query to return tons of results. But with only a limited number of results it is working like a charm.

Comment: there are tons(about 10000) of results, so what i need is to get then full particular Licence with owner included when I search it by ID.

Comment: @CodeDemen That's exactly what you get by this query.

Comment: @CodeDemen: As far as I can see from your model, the query I gave you should actually return a List<Keys> (or is it List<License>. Can't say for sure?) containing a single item IF Owner is a one to zero/one relationship (which it should be. Otherwise you'd need to have a collection of UserProfile objects instead of a single UserProfile)